# Why multiple mongodb connecions with Casbah?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have to manage multiple databases connection to MongoDb, using casbah scala client. I have an approximation that works **but open hundreds of connections.**

I want to save a Map[String, MongoDB] that saves a connection for each database (which is the key.  I'm using this in Spark Streaming with a two nodes cluster, so **I think that is a serialization issue but I don't know how to fix it**.

Take a look to my class.

```
abstract class AbstractMongoDAO(@transient val config: Config) extends Closeable with Serializable {

      @transient private val mongoConfig = config.getConfig(CONFIG_KEY)
      private val host = mongoConfig.getString(CONFIG_KEY_HOST)

      @transient private var _mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(host)
      private var _dbs: mutable.HashMap[String, MongoDB] = mutable.HashMap()

      protected  def dbs(): mutable.HashMap[String, MongoDB] ={
        if(_dbs == null)
          _dbs = mutable.HashMap()
        _dbs
      }

      def mongoClient: MongoClient = {
        if (_mongoClient == null) {
          _mongoClient = MongoClient(host)
        }
        _mongoClient
      }

      def db(dbName: String):MongoDB =  {
        if (dbs.get(dbName) == None) {
          _dbs += (dbName ->  mongoClient.getDB(dbName))
        }
        _dbs.get(dbName).get
      }

      override def close() = {
        Option(_mongoClient).foreach(_.close())
      }

    }

    private object AbstractMongoDAO {
      val CONFIG_KEY = "mongo"
      val CONFIG_KEY_HOST = "host"

    }
```

And then I have another class that extends AbstractMongoDao

```
class MongoDAO (override val config : Config)
  extends AbstractMongoDAO(config) with Serializable
```

And I get a db connection with this simple code. appName is a variable database.

```
val _db = db(appName)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Casbah is built on top of official [Java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver). `MongoClient` represents an internal pool of db connections to a MongoDB cluster. If you use the same cluster and only change database name and not the host, you don't need to create multiple `MongoClient`s, one would be enough for the whole application.

To configure `MongoClient` check [this](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) documentation and corresponding [options](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html). If you have multiple DB hosts or still want to use multiple `MongoClient`s then you can build your options and create `MongoClient` like this:

```
val options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .connectionsPerHost(1)
            // add other options if needed
            .build();

 val _mongoClient = MongoClient(host, options)
```

In your case since only db name neeeds to change and not the db host I would change the method that gets db to this:

```
  def db(dbName: String):MongoDB =
    mongoClient.getDB(dbName) // db will be created in Mongo on the fly if not exist
```

And you don't need the map anymore.

Comment: I did what you told me but still creates multiple connections... I put connections in a companion object with your mongoclientoptions and now  works correctly. Thank you.